# Is this usage of "instead" correct - 'use x to y instead'?

Tags: word-usage

I have seen the below mentioned sentence, where x has to be replaced by y.

> use x to y instead

Is this usage of the word *instead* correct?

**Edit**: There was one post where one wrong word was written (lets assume it word1), then writer left a comment "use word1 to word2 instead", word2 is correct word. But this sentence sounds bit wrong to me.

Comment: I think this statement needs a little more context.

Comment: You say that you've seen this construction... can you please give us an actual example rather than this example fragment? In general, I would say this is a poor construction choice but knowing the entire sentence could change that.

Comment: Probably the form you want is *Use Y **instead of** X*.

Comment: ...of course, it could be a "use/mention" context, where the writer might have been commenting on someone else having written ***Heavens to Betsy!*** with something like *Older people often use **Heavens to Murgatroyd**!* instead*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume the original author wrote:

> There were ten gooses in the yard.

An editor might say any of these:

> - "Change *gooses* to *geese*.
> - "Use *geese* instead of *gooses*."
> - "Change *gooses* and use *geese* instead."

The version you reportedly saw:

> - "Use *gooses* to *geese* instead."

sounds like an inadvertent blend of these, but I don't think it works.

Comment: ... and probably "Instead of _gooses_, use _geese_."